# Given a set of sets, how to efficiently find sets that have at least 1 member in common?

Tags: java, algorithm

Let's say we're given a set of sets, for example:

```java
Set<String> s1 = Set.of("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "7");
Set<String> s2 = Set.of("10", "20", "30", "40", "50");
Set<String> s3 = Set.of("100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "7", "9");
Set<String> s4 = Set.of("1000", "2000", "3000", "4000", "5000");
Set<String> s5 = Set.of("100000", "200000", "300000", "400000", "500000", "9");
```

How to find the collection of sets where there is member intersection?   In this example, s1 and s3 have overlap as do s3 and s5.

The inefficient solution would be to

```java
List<Set<String>> sets = List.of(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);
for (Set<String> tester : sets) {
    sets.remove(tester);
    for (String s: tester) {
        for (Set<String> target : sets) {
            if (target.contains(s)) {
                // record match
            }
        }
    }
```

Can a better time complexity be acheived?

Comment: How big are the sets? How many of them are there? You can do it fairly easily why shoving the whole lot into a `Map` but that might be prohibitive.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're only interested in listing all *pairs* of sets with 1+ elements in common, and don't need to list out all groups of 3 or more sets with nonempty intersection?

Comment: @BoristheSpider - let's say under 1million.   do you mean use the strings as key to a map with lists of sets as values?

Comment: @marathon that was my thought yeah. Or indices of the sets in the list of sets. 1m might be a bit expensive though.

Comment: I would probably have done something like `For(int i = 0; i < sets.Count; i++)
{
   string firstVar = sets[i].Where(setVar => sets.Where(x => x.Contains(setVar))).ToList;....
}`

Comment: I would have done it the same way as Boris the Spider, I don't think you can get better time complexity than that. Just better space complexity. The values of the map should be a set of indices in my opinion.

Comment: @maraca probably makes very little difference as they’re going to likely be 64 bit aligned anyway and are going to have to be boxed. I would take a look at Eclipse Collections primitive collections perhaps for efficiency. But yeah, think time complexity that’s the best you can do.

Comment: Btw. the easy way would be to do pairwise comparison and to compare a and b you make a (shallow) copy of a and then call aCopy.retainAll(b), so you know which elements are in both sets. You don't have to iterate all the strings manually as in your example.

Comment: If there's a better way than constructing the inverted index, reporting all of the pairs in each posting list, and deduplicating the result, I don't know about it.

Comment: If the elements are comparable you could transform each ```Set``` into a ```Map``` and then run a sliding window on iterators on each map. The nice thing about this approach is that the window size will only be O(number of sets); if we can't store both the original copy of sets and the transformed maps into memory at the same time, we could always re-convert the maps back into sets.

Comment: @wLui155 sorting isn’t free however.

Comment: I definitely find myself wondering about using Bloom filters as a first pass?  That might not actually buy you anything in the end, though.